# change color of graphic element on click and add to displayed dollar amount

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to have graphic elements on a page, each representing the same dollar value. By default, these elements will be the same color (white) and a base dollar amount (total) will be visible. Users would then be able to click on a graphic element(s) and change its color (yellow) and in doing so, increase the dollar amount (total) shown. They should also be able to click on yellow graphic element to "deactivate it" and change its color back to white. Also, in doing so subtract from total - or at least click a reset button to turn all elements back to default.

How can I phrase my search query so that I can get better results or for any web references that can help me piece together a solution.

Comment: If you can add a fiddle or code, we would be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Sameera, will do. I'll be studying Muhammad's suggestion and will try to  make it work for my needs. I'll post here for review once complete. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is working: http://jsfiddle.net/9tdgxuh9/

```
var box = $('.box');
var price = 10;
var n = 5;

while (n--) box.clone().appendTo($('body'));

box = $('.box');

box.find('.color').click(function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass('yellow').siblings('p').text(price);
});


box.find('p').text(price).click(function(){
    var val = parseInt($(this).text())+1;
    $(this).text(val);
    if (val>price) $(this).siblings('.color').addClass('yellow');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Muhammad, for quick response. I'll study your suggestion. I'll be looking to modify so that there is only one visible $ total, perhaps in div.total and only adding/subtracting once per click per .box. So in the above example, if three boxes were yellow, then total would be $30.